# Регистрация библиотеки в GAC и не только

Tags: visual-studio, dll, gac

Программирую в  Visual Studio.

Задача установить проект через setup клиенту.

Итак, у меня есть 2 .dll - *AnyGacLib.dll* и *AnyDirLib.dll*. Одна записывается в GAC, а другая записывается в директорию установки программы (допустим Program Files).

Возникло пару вопросов:

1. Если библиотека в GAC зависит от любой другой библиотеки, то она то же должна быть зарегистрирована ?
2. Что бы зарегистрировать библиотеку *AnyGacLib.dll* в GAC, можно использовать настройку "регистрация для COM-взаимодействия" в свойствах сборки проекта. В таком случае все сборки, от которых зависит эта либа УЖе должны быть зарегистрированы там же ? (а то он выдает ошибку что не нашел сборку). Как я понял все зависимые сборки он не регистрирует.
3. Исходя из п.1, если *AnyGaclib* зависит от *AnyDirLib*, но при этом *AnyDirLib* не может никак быть записана в GAC, то получается нужно делать 2 копии *AnyDirLib* - в гак и в директорию установки?